# magento - how to debug? product not visible, cloned product not visible, new product is visible

Tags: debugging, magento

we have one of the famous "product not visible in frontend" problems, but this one seems to be a bit harder.

we certainly worked the checklist (like this one http://www.aschroder.com/2010/07/why-are-my-magento-products-not-showing-up/) but still:

this product 404s:
http://www.in-due.de/hochzeitsshop/catalog/product/view/id/15034

this one is a clone and 404s:
http://www.in-due.de/hochzeitsshop/catalog/product/view/id/15745

this product is new and works perfectly:
http://www.in-due.de/hochzeitsshop/catalog/product/view/id/15746

what is the best approach to debug this problem?

PAT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to go over this checklist

- Status should be enabled
- Inventory should be positive and In Stock
- Should be assigned less to one active category
- Go to Index Manager and Reindex all

If not helps try to debug starting from Catalog product  controller, view action.

Hope it helps.

**UPD**: thanks for answer, there really should be one more point

- product should be assigned to desired store (which you are checking on the front) on the "Websites" tab

Comment: Don't forget to check if the product attribute is_salable is set and in that case that it is set to '1', not '0'

Answer (score 1):

As so often.. we went over the checklist, but overlooked one point:

check that the product is not only active on the global level but also on the store view level. some %$^%** disabled it there..